# make a draggable obstacle = all items except self

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to set the .obstacle of a draggable item to all other item EXCEPT itself.
The current code is working but I will need to setup a separate obstacle for each ID.
In the example, I'm only using 3 Items, but the working code will need to contain 100 eventually so I was looking for a way to avoid having to manually code each one.

```
$("#item1, #item2,#item3 ").draggable({
 preventCollision: true,
 containment: "#moveInHere"
});

$("#item1").draggable({
    obstacle: "#item2,#item3" ,
});
$("#item2").draggable({
    obstacle: "#item1,#item3" ,
});
$("#item3").draggable({
    obstacle: "#item1,#item2" ,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give all draggable elements the same class, then initialize them that way.

To avoid manual coding, you could try this:

```
$('.widget').draggable({
  drag: function(event,ui) {
    $('.widget').not($(this)).draggable('option', 'obstacle', '.widget');
  }
});
```

This will select every draggable element except the current dragged element.